# State management not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, state

In my application, I want to keep track of multiple states. Thus I tried to encapsulate the whole state management logic within a class `StateManager` as follows:

```
@SerialVersionUID(xxxxxxxL)
class StateManager(
    inputStream: DStream[(String, String)],
    initialState: RDD[(String, String)]
) extends Serializable {
  lazy val state = inputStream.mapWithState(stateSpec).map(_.get)
  lazy val stateSpec = StateSpec
    .function(trackStateFunc _)
    .initialState(initialState)
    .timeout(Seconds(30))
  def trackStateFunc(key: String, value: Option[String], state: State[String]): Option[(String, String)] = {}
}

object StateManager { def apply(dstream: DStream[(String, String)], initialstate: RDD[(String, String)]) = new StateManager(_dStream, _initialState) }
```

The `@SerialVersionUID(xxxxxxxL) ... extends Serializable` is an attempt to solve my problem.

But when calling `StateManager` from my main class like the following:

```
val lStreamingContext = StreamingEnvironment(streamingWindow, checkpointDirectory)
val statemanager= StateManager(lStreamingEnvironment.sparkContext, 1, None)
val state= statemanager.state(lKafkaStream)

state.foreachRDD(_.foreach(println))
```

(see below for `StreamingEnvironment`), I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
[...]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized  possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because  the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure.  Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this.  This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks  with unnecessary objects.
```

The error is clear, but still I don't get on what point does it trigger.

Where does it trigger?
What could I do to solve this and have a reusable class?

---

The might-be-useful `StreamingEnvironment` class:

```
class StreamingEnvironment(mySparkConf: SparkConf, myKafkaConf: KafkaConf, myStreamingWindow: Duration, myCheckPointDirectory: String) {
  val sparkContext = spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(mySparkConf)
  lazy val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext , mMicrobatchPeriod)

  streamingContext.checkpoint(mCheckPointDirectory)
  streamingContext.remember(Minutes(1))

  def stream() = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](streamingContext, myKafkaConf.mBrokers, myKafkaConf.mTopics)
}

object StreamingEnvironment {
  def apply(streamingWindow: Duration, checkpointDirectory: String) = {
    //setup sparkConf and kafkaConf

    new StreamingEnvironment(sparkConf , kafkaConf, streamingWindow, checkpointDirectory)
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your Spark graph.

Comment: The graph you build using `StreamingContext`.

Comment: Edit done with utility class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we lift a method into a function, the `outer` reference to the parent class will be part of that function reference, like here: `function(trackStateFunc _)`
Declaring `trackStateFunc` directly as a function (i.e. as a `val`) will probably take care of the problem.

Also note that marking a class `Serializable` does not make it magically so. DStream is not serializable and should be annotated as `@transient`, which will probably solve the issue as well.